# LWJGL Hello World throws Exception

Tags: java, lwjgl, illegalstateexception

I'm following [this LWJGL Getting started guide](https://www.lwjgl.org/guide) which is supposed to show a window, but I'm getting this error which suggests running on the main thread and initialising AWT or JavaFX prior. How does one do that?

I have set -XstartOnFirstThread in VM options. I'm on MacOS 10.13.2

I started the project by selecting a new Gradle project in IDEA, and then I used the LWJGL Gradle generator to generate build.gradle.

I followed the IDEA steps in the [installation guide](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3-wiki/wiki/1.2.-Install) but I didn't understand what they meant by (I don't think it's too relevant to my error):

> If you want to match the Maven/Gradle behavior exactly, you could create 2 separate libraries:
>   One with the class+source .jar files, make it a compile dependency of your module(s).
>   One with the natives .jar files, make it a runtime dependency of your module(s).
>   You can do this in the Project Structure > Modules > select a module > Dependencies tab, by changing the Scope of each dependency.

The error on "gradle run":

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwCreateWindow(GLFW.java:1694)
at com.javagame.kasha.HelloWorld.init(HelloWorld.java:51)
at com.javagame.kasha.HelloWorld.run(HelloWorld.java:24)
at com.javagame.kasha.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:114)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GLFW windows may only be created on the main thread and that thread must be the first thread in the process. Please run the JVM with -XstartOnFirstThread. For offscreen rendering, make sure another window toolkit (e.g. AWT or JavaFX) is initialized before GLFW.
at org.lwjgl.glfw.EventLoop$OffScreen.<clinit>(EventLoop.java:39)
... 4 more
:run FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command   '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java''   finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED in 0s
```

HelloWorld.java (copied from the guide, I added a package so I can start it using the Gradle application plugin):

```
package com.javagame.kasha;

import org.lwjgl.*;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.*;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.*;
import org.lwjgl.system.*;

import java.nio.*;

import static org.lwjgl.glfw.Callbacks.*;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.*;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.*;

public class HelloWorld {

// The window handle
private long window;

public void run() {
    System.out.println("Hello LWJGL " + Version.getVersion() + "!");

    init();
    loop();

    // Free the window callbacks and destroy the window
    glfwFreeCallbacks(window);
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);

    // Terminate GLFW and free the error callback
    glfwTerminate();
    glfwSetErrorCallback(null).free();
}

private void init() {
    // Setup an error callback. The default implementation
    // will print the error message in System.err.
    GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err).set();

    // Initialize GLFW. Most GLFW functions will not work before doing this.
    if ( !glfwInit() )
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize GLFW");

    // Configure GLFW
    glfwDefaultWindowHints(); // optional, the current window hints are already the default
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE); // the window will stay hidden after creation
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_TRUE); // the window will be resizable

    // Create the window
    window = glfwCreateWindow(300, 300, "Hello World!", NULL, NULL);
    if ( window == NULL )
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create the GLFW window");

    // Setup a key callback. It will be called every time a key is pressed, repeated or released.
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, (window, key, scancode, action, mods) -> {
        if ( key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_RELEASE )
            glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true); // We will detect this in the rendering loop
    });

    // Get the thread stack and push a new frame
    try ( MemoryStack stack = stackPush() ) {
        IntBuffer pWidth = stack.mallocInt(1); // int*
        IntBuffer pHeight = stack.mallocInt(1); // int*

        // Get the window size passed to glfwCreateWindow
        glfwGetWindowSize(window, pWidth, pHeight);

        // Get the resolution of the primary monitor
        GLFWVidMode vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());

        // Center the window
        glfwSetWindowPos(
                window,
                (vidmode.width() - pWidth.get(0)) / 2,
                (vidmode.height() - pHeight.get(0)) / 2
        );
    } // the stack frame is popped automatically

    // Make the OpenGL context current
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    // Enable v-sync
    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    // Make the window visible
    glfwShowWindow(window);
}

private void loop() {
    // This line is critical for LWJGL's interoperation with GLFW's
    // OpenGL context, or any context that is managed externally.
    // LWJGL detects the context that is current in the current thread,
    // creates the GLCapabilities instance and makes the OpenGL
    // bindings available for use.
    GL.createCapabilities();

    // Set the clear color
    glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    // Run the rendering loop until the user has attempted to close
    // the window or has pressed the ESCAPE key.
    while ( !glfwWindowShouldClose(window) ) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // clear the framebuffer

        glfwSwapBuffers(window); // swap the color buffers

        // Poll for window events. The key callback above will only be
        // invoked during this call.
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new HelloWorld().run();
}

}
```

build.gradle:

```
group 'javagame'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'


import org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem

switch ( OperatingSystem.current() ) {
    case OperatingSystem.WINDOWS:
        project.ext.lwjglNatives = "natives-windows"
        break
    case OperatingSystem.LINUX:
        project.ext.lwjglNatives = "natives-linux"
        break
    case OperatingSystem.MAC_OS:
        project.ext.lwjglNatives = "natives-macos"
        break
}


apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
project.ext.lwjglVersion = "3.1.5"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

mainClassName = "com.javagame.kasha.HelloWorld"

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile "org.lwjgl:lwjgl:$lwjglVersion"
    compile "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-assimp:$lwjglVersion"
    compile "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-glfw:$lwjglVersion"
    compile "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-openal:$lwjglVersion"
    compile "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-opengl:$lwjglVersion"
    compile "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-stb:$lwjglVersion"
    compile "org.lwjgl:lwjgl:$lwjglVersion:$lwjglNatives"
    compile "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-assimp:$lwjglVersion:$lwjglNatives"
    compile "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-glfw:$lwjglVersion:$lwjglNatives"
    compile "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-openal:$lwjglVersion:$lwjglNatives"
    compile "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-opengl:$lwjglVersion:$lwjglNatives"
    compile "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-stb:$lwjglVersion:$lwjglNatives"
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It was a problem related to my configuration of Gradle and the application plugin. The solution is to put the arguments in the build.grade directly, instead of run configuration:

```
applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["-XstartOnFirstThread"]
```